# Is there a way to only limit the lower range in mysql?

Tags: mysql, limit

I want to get all the rows but the first in my query. How can I do this?

Comment: `LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615`

Comment: `LIMIT 1, 99999999` offset of one eliminates the first row. Make the upper bound higher than your total rows.

Comment: If you guys posted these as answers, you'd get real upvotes :)

Comment: @mellamokb: does this number 18446744073709551615 has any significance?

Comment: @arunmoezhi: That's the number used in the example for using `LIMIT` for getting last n rows in the [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).  Presumably it's the largest possible number you can use in a `LIMIT` clause and happens to be 2^64 - 1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very large number of rows with an offset of `1`.

```
LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615
```