# mySQL - LIMIT syntax to get all the rows after a certain point?

Tags: mysql, limit

I hope this is a very easy answer:

I can use

```
LIMIT 2,4
```

to give me records 3,4,5,6

How can I get all the records from 3 onwards? If I use

```
LIMIT 2
```

It will just give me the first 2 rows? Right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to only limit the lower range in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641749/is-there-a-way-to-only-limit-the-lower-range-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 3rd row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 2,18446744073709551615;
```

[Taken from the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adf0/2)

Comment: I believe you mean `LIMIT 2,1844...` but yes

Comment: I'm not sure how many computers have enough memory for 18446744073709551615 rows. Even at one byte each that's impossible, it'd be 16 exabytes.

Comment: Well, I want my answer being update-to-date in 100 years too ;)